# Specified element is already the logical child of another element for 2 Labels

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and I tried the code below :

```
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="two" Content="text"/>
    <Label x:Name="one" Content="{Binding ElementName=two}"/>      
</Grid>
```

I got error saying

> Specified element is already the logical child of another element

From googling I understood that I have a control which is already a child to some control and I am trying to assign it to another one as its child.

Which I did not figure it out in my code.

What may cause the problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By writing `Content="{Binding ElementName=two}"` you try to add the `Label` named `two` to the `Content` of the `Label` named `one`. This would result to the `Label` `two` being a child of the `Grid` AND the `Label` `one`s `Content`.

Comment: @LittleBit : so If I understood the logic, the Content of a label is seen as an object and not as a property.

So in my case : Content of label one will be in one hand a child to the label one and I am tryng to assign it to another label which makes the content child to both Lables ?

Comment: Not quite: The `Content` is a `Property` with the Property Value `object`. The problem is: the `Binding` `{Binding ElementName=two}` passes a reference to the `Label` `two` itself and therefore there are two references to the `Label` `two` in different parents. One Parent is the `Grid` and the other one `Label` `one`, one could say the `Label` `two` should exist within the `Grid` and the `Content` of `Label` `one` (which is not possible as you can see in the Error). I hope this explains a little bit better.

Comment: @LittleBit : yeah a bit better. So doing a label having its content the content of another label is impossible. Snap ! there is no way to do it with XAML ?

Comment: It is possible if the `Content` is not a `UIElement`. Try binding to its Content, rather than the element itself -> see mm8 Answer.

Comment: @LittleBit : I thought there is no need to specify the path as Content for label One.
now I got it . thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the `Content` property of `two`:

```
<Label x:Name="one" Content="{Binding Content, ElementName=two}"/>
```

But a visual element can only appear *once* in the visual tree, so you can't bind the `Content` property to the `Label` itself.

By the way, if you want to display text, you should prefer `TextBlocks` over `Labels`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="two" Text="text"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="one" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=two}"/>
```